# Optimize per-element operation on sparse numpy 2D array

Tags: numpy, matrix, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I require `M = np.log(1+M)` on a large 99.9% sparse 2D matrix.

How to perform this efficiently?

`x, y = M.nonzero()` will retrieve coord-pairs of nonzero elements, but can I vectorize a `log` operation over these pairs?

numpy doesn't seem to have `sparse` support.

Comment: `scipy` has a `sparse` module.  But I wouldn't use it just for this `log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simplest:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

M = sps.csr_matrix(M)

M.data += 1
M.data = np.log(M.data)
```

If it's particularly large you could also log it in place (this prevents the full copy above):

```
M.data += 1
M.data=np.log(M.data,out=M.data)
```

Both of these options work on dense matrices as well with minor changes - if your matrix is 99.9% sparse I would start using actual sparse data structures though.

You could also use the `where` argument on a dense array, but I doubt it would actually be any faster:

```
M = np.add(M, 1, out=M, where=M!=0)
M = np.log(M, out=M, where=M!=0)
```

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to also show the way how to perform the log in place: `M.data=np.log(M.data,out=M.data)` Chunking isn't necessary here.

Comment: @max9111 Oh, good idea - I didn't actually know you could give `out` the same array.

Comment: Note that numpy has `log1p` (log one plus)